# Android Studio не видит файлы

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

Ошибка Android Studio:

```
error: resource drawable/nav_settings (aka success.kneu:drawable/nav_settings) not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource drawable/nav_settings (aka success.kneu:drawable/nav_settings) not found., sources=[C:\Users\roman\Desktop\KNEU_SUCCESS\app\src\main\res\menu\navigation.xml:16], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь видит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Студию релогал, в системе файлы видно.

Comment: да, в `res/drawable` лежат.

Comment: Build -> Rebuild project

Comment: Это не помогает, я думаю это ошибка студии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю что это ошибка самой студии, т.к. `Rebuild Project`, `Restart` итд. не помогли. Но у меня получилось это исправить:

1. Я перетащил иконки в другое место.
2. Удалил все расположение ресурсов в xml.
3. Сделал `Rebuild Project`.
4. Залил иконки обратно в папку `drawable`.
5. Добавил иконки заново в меню.

Заработало. Возможно я не прав, но это работает...